# JavaScript Server element onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, element, getelementbyid

Html

```
<a id="lnkShowExportBtn" runat="server">Look at image</a>
```

jQuery

```
lnkShowExportBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", @"{ var rowImage = document.getElementById('rowImage');
    if(rowImage.style.display == 'none')
           {
            rowImage.style.display = 'block';
            var lnkShowExportBtn = document.getElementById('<%=lnkShowExportBtn.ClientID%>');
            lnkShowExportBtn.innerHTML = 'Hide image';
          }
    else  {
            rowImage.style.display = 'none';
            var lnkShowExportBtn = document.getElementById('<%=lnkShowExportBtn.ClientID%>');
            lnkShowExportBtn.innerHTML = 'Look at image';
          }
}");
```

---

Get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

What am I doing wrong? Just can't get to the point.

Thanks.

Comment: you are using lnkShowExportBtn for 'lnkShowExportBtn.Attributes' and same variable for getElementById. change it first.

Comment: But I need to change its html text onclick. How it is possible to do, man? Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `'<%=lnkShowExportBtn.ClientID%>'` as a string and it is **not evaluated** to replace the real client id value, which you can see in the generated html. It would be a lot more simple if you add javascript in aspx and just bind it on server side.

*In code behind*

```
lnkShowExportBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "YourFunction()");
```

OR, in ASPX

```
<a id="lnkShowExportBtn" runat="server" onclick="YourFunction();">Look at image</a>
```

*In javascript*

```
function YourFunction() 
{   
  var rowImage = document.getElementById('rowImage');
  if (rowImage.style.display == 'none') {
      rowImage.style.display = 'block';
      var lnkShowExportBtn = document.getElementById('<%=lnkShowExportBtn.ClientID%>');
      lnkShowExportBtn.innerHTML = 'Hide image';
  } else {
      rowImage.style.display = 'none';
      var lnkShowExportBtn = document.getElementById('<%=lnkShowExportBtn.ClientID%>');
      lnkShowExportBtn.innerHTML = 'Look at image';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery : Here I have bind click event to `lnkShowExportBtn` and changing inner html of it with the help of if condition which checks of image visible. And by using `.toggle()`, I am making image hide and show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#lnkShowExportBtn').click(function(){
       var innerHtml = 'Hide image';
       if($('.rowImage').is(':visible'))
      {
        innerHtml = 'Look at image';
      }
      $(this).html(innerHtml);
      $('.rowImage').toggle();
   });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hw4zt/3/)**

For more Information on jQuery : **[click jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)**